# Return multiple json.UnmarshalTypeError errors

Tags: go

Just getting to grips with GO and loving it. I've come across a small issue and I can't seem to over come it.

I have an array of errors returning using `validator.Validate`. I have a `POST` endpoint which has two required fields. If none of these fields are in the `body`, I will get back an array of errors stating these are required.

My Issue However, If I send over the incorrect data type on one of these (`string`), it will validate the input one by one. For example:

This is working as intedned with nothing sent in the body

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klhEP.png)

And below, is sending over name and testingvalidation as an integer

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LchZ.png)

How do I get my code to not just validate the one above? I noticed if the error is a type of `json.UnmarshalTypeError` then it will only return one error

Comment: Can you please add your code as text instead of an image?